# Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable while building

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen, instantiation

Peeps, I'm lost. Tried everything and after 5 hours of searching through the 10th page of Google hits, I give up. Maybe I just dont know how to ask Google the correct keywords..

I have this scenario: In lumen app, lets call it X, I have require custom packages CRUD and Storage, Storage is using functionality of CRUD.

StorageService has:

```
use Crud\Services\BaseService;
class StorageService extends BaseService{}
```

And Crud\BaseService has constructor, that uses Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class BaseService
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

When I try to do anything with my app X, I get error:

```
Target [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model] is not instantiable while building [Lumee\Storage\Services\StorageService]
```

I cannot get my head around how to get to proper class of Model, since I saw, that Model is abstract class.

Also, I'm using this CRUD package successfully in another App, only difference is, there CRUD is used directly in app, not via some other package. I'm confused, why there is working without any additional bindings and service registering..

EDIT: Added some binding into StorageServiceProvider (boot and register methods):

```
        $this->app->bind(BaseService::class, function(){
        return new BaseService(new Model());
    });
```

And registered StorageServiceProvider in my boostrap/app.php:

```
$app->register(Storage\Providers\StorageServiceProvider::class);
```

Thing still returns same error. I tried with binding in CrudServiceProvider, nope.

Comment: You can't resolve this `BaseService` class automatically since you have it set to depend on `Model` which can not be instantiated ... you would need some type of binding if you want to resolve this Service class from the container as it needs to know how to resolve `Model` (which could be anything that extends `Model` as well)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On which level should I bind it? I tried to keep my code as minimal as possible, must I really introduce CrudServiceProvider? I tried with $this->app->bind(BaseService::class, function(){
            return new BaseService(new Model());
        }); in StorageServiceProvider, which is also registered in X->boostrap/app.php.

Comment: I edited some additional info into OP

Comment: Where is the $this->app->bind(BaseService::class, ...) is it added in boot or register?

Comment: I tried adding it to both functions to no avail. Can they be put into both function at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't get object from abstract class (Model class) to solve this try this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class BaseService
{
    protected $model;

}
```

suppose your model is (Storage) :

```
use Crud\Services\BaseService;
class StorageService extends BaseService{

        public function __construct(Storage $model)
        {
            $this->model = $model;
        }
}
```