# Target [Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model] is not instantiable while building

Tags: php, laravel, repository

gets an error when everything is implemented correctly

```
    "message": "Target [Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model] is not instantiable while building [App\\Http\\Services\\TournamentService, App\\Http\\Repository\\Tournament\\TournamentRepository].",
```

MY CODE:
CONTROLLER:

```
public function getTournamentUserByType(TournamentService $tournamentService)
{
  $tounaments = $tournamentService->getAll();
}
```

SERVICE:

```
class TournamentService implements TournamentServiceInterface
{
    private TournamentRepositoryInterface $tournamentRepository;

    public function __construct(TournamentRepositoryInterface $tournamentRepository)
    {
        $this->tournamentRepository = $tournamentRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getAll(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tournamentRepository->all();
    }
```

REPOSITORY INTERFACE:

```
interface TournamentRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function all(): Collection;
```

MY REPOSITORY:

```
class TournamentRepository extends BaseRepository implements TournamentRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Model $model
     */
    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function all(): Collection
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }
```

Everything looks correct, I completely don't know why it gives me this error

Comment: You've got a repository interface, but what does your repository look like? Does it bring in a raw Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model somewhere, like in the constructor?

Comment: i add in the post

Comment: Gotcha! Based on that, does this answer your question? [Target \[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\] is not instantiable while building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743149/target-illuminate-database-eloquent-model-is-not-instantiable-while-building)

Comment: Ok solved, the issue is to use a specific Model in a specific Repo. E.g. in TournamentRepository use Tournament $model in the constructor.... Thanks very much for your help!